# Concept on "best constant's loss" in vowpal wabbit's output, and the stated rule of thumb in tutorial

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am trying to understand vowpal a bit more and came across this statement on the Linear Regression tutorial. (https://vowpalwabbit.org/tutorials/getting_started.html)

"At the end, some more straightforward totals are printed. The best constant and best constant's loss only work if you are using squared loss. Squared loss is the Vowpal Wabbit default. They compute the best constant’s predictor and the loss of the best constant predictor.

If average loss is not better than best constant's loss, something is wrong. In this case, we have too few examples to generalize."

Based on that context, I have 2 related questions:

1. Is the best constant's loss based on the loss of the null model in linear regression?
2. Is the general rule of thumb for "average loss" not being better than "best constant's loss" applicable to all loss functions (since the statement does state that the "best constant" only works for the default squared loss function)?

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is the best constant's loss based on the loss of the null model in linear regression?

If by *null-model* you mean the model which always predicts the best-constant, then yes.

#### Is the general rule of thumb for "average loss" not being better than "best constant's loss" applicable to all loss functions?

Yes. If by always using the same prediction (some best constant applicable to a given loss-function) you are doing better than the learned model, it means that the learned model is inferior to the simplest possible model. The simplest model for a given loss-function, is always predicting the same (best constant) result, ignoring the input-features in the data.

One of the most common cases for a learned model being inferior to the best-constant model, is a too small data-set. When the data-set is small, the learning process didn't have a chance to fully converge yet. This is also known as under-fitting.

#### How is the best constant calculated (for completeness)?

In the case of linear-regression (least-squares hyperplane, the `vw --loss_function squared`, which is the default) the best constant is the *simple average* (aka *mean*) of the labels. This minimizes the squared-loss.

In the case of *quantile-loss* (aka absolute-error, `vw --loss_function quantile`) the best constant is the *median* of the labels and it minimizes the sum-of-distances between the labels and the prediction.

Comment: Thank you @arielf for the extra complete answer! That really helps with framing my understanding!

Comment: What is the best constant model for logistic loss?